# necessitas - can't compile any project

Tags: android, qt, sdk, android-ndk

I just installed necessitas on ubuntu 13.04 , on the package qtcreator , then i tried to compile the simplest project i could, which is a project just created, and even trying different AVDs with different APIs nothing changes.
It returns:

> :-1: error: [install_target] Error 1 (ignored)

and

> :-1: error: Can't copy gdbserver from '/home/federico/necessitas/android-ndk/prebuilt/android-arm/gdbserver/gdbserver' to '/home/federico/Android Projects/Hello-World/android/libs/armeabi/gdbserver'

Hope that this can help other people, because I didn't find anything on the web that really could help me.

Here is the compile output:

> 11:26:52: Running steps for project Hello-World...
>   11:26:52: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
>   11:26:52: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
>   make: Nothing to be done for `first'.
>   11:26:52: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
>   11:26:52: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 'INSTALL_ROOT=/home/federico/Android Projects/Hello-World/android' install
>   /bin/sh: 1: test: /home/federico/Android: unexpected operator
>   install -m 755 -p "libHello-World.so" "/home/federico/Android Projects/Hello-World/android/libs/armeabi/libHello-World.so"
>   install: cannot create regular file '/home/federico/Android Projects/Hello-World/android/libs/armeabi/libHello-World.so': No such file or directory
>   make: [install_target] Error 1 (ignored)
>   11:26:52: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
>   11:26:52: Copy Qt app & libs to Android package ...
>   Can't copy gdbserver from '/home/federico/necessitas/android-ndk/prebuilt/android-arm/gdbserver/gdbserver' to '/home/federico/Android Projects/Hello-World/android/libs/armeabi/gdbserver'
>   Error while building/deploying project Hello-World (kit: Android for arm (GCC 4.6, Qt 4.8.2))
>   When executing step 'Packaging for Android'
>   11:26:52: Elapsed time: 00:00.

Comment: "cannot create regular file '/home/federico/Android Projects/Hello-World/android/libs/armeabi/libHello-World.so': No such file or directory"  Sounds like a possible file permissions problem?

Comment: sound strange, because the directory in which i save qt projects is also in /home/federico and that does not give problems..

Comment: It might be farther down the chain.  Can your user create a text file in that libs folder?  Does that file already exist and is read-only?  For that matter, does the libs directory exist?

Comment: i can create files in android directory. libs directory does not exist, but i believe qt is supposed to create it...

Comment: No, qt isn't.  The NDK should make the armeabi dir, but I think the libs directory needs to already exist-  or at least it used to.  Try making that directory and trying again

Comment: if i create libs directory it returns the same errors. If i create also armeabi directory inside libs , and copy gdbserver from android-ndk directory and put into armeabi then it returns another error: :-1: error: Packaging Error: Command '/usr/bin/ant clean debug' failed.Exit code: 1